# How to access to postgresql on vagranted virtual machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chef-infra, vagrant

I make via Vagrant virtual machine with postgresql and want to use it as my rails app database.

I use similar Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.18"
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    # I take cookbook from https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql
    chef.add_recipe "postgresql::server"
    chef.json = {
      postgresql: {
        config: {
          ssl: false,
          listen_addresses: '*'
        },
        password: {
          postgres: 'postgres'
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Next I `vagrant up` and expect that next `database.yml` will be worked:

```
development:
  database: app_development
  adapter: postgresql
  host: '192.168.33.18'
  username: root
```

But this is not happen.. Rake task fails with error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "192.168.33.18" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

And I see that port is actually not opened

```
$ nmap -p 5432 192.168.33.18

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-05-07 22:05 FET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.33.18
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

And I can see some postgres processes  on vm, and there no any errors in vagrant output, so I believe postgres works normally.

```
  932 postgres  20   0  126m 9.9m 8916 S    0  2.7   0:00.03 

postgres                                                                                                             
  941 postgres  20   0 97460 1348  192 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 postgres                                                                                                             
  944 postgres  20   0  126m 1728  548 S    0  0.5   0:00.06 postgres                                                                                                             
  945 postgres  20   0  126m 1488  316 S    0  0.4   0:00.05 postgres                                                                                                             
  946 postgres  20   0  126m 2768 1000 S    0  0.7   0:00.00 postgres                                                                                                             
  947 postgres  20   0 97456 1584  352 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 postgres
```

How to setup Vagrant to use db on virtual machine in my rails app?

**UPDATE** my `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer

###########
# Other authentication configurations taken from chef node defaults:
###########

local   all             all                                     trust

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: Maybe you need some settings for postgresql server to start? Can you provide the vagrant log?

Comment: I update my vagrantfile (actually it bigger, because there are another cookbooks). And also provide some additional data from virtual machine

Comment: Postgres uses a configuration file called _pg_hba.conf_ to control connection access.  I don't know how chef or vagrant manages that file; in a plain postgres installation, you'd just edit it.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad I update my Q. with `pg_hba.conf`  - could you look on it? Though I think my app even can't acccess on vm, not in db

Comment: Your pg_hba.conf looks alright.  Your trouble must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I apologize to all readers, but problem was in my inattention. Though I point `listen_addresses: '*'` in config, then I reset this config accidentally, so in final config was taken default `listen_addresses: 'localhost'` value. After fix this port became opened.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  Be sure to give your answer the check mark.