# Can someone point out why I can't connect to PGSQL on guest from host? (vagrant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vagrant

I have been working on this for awhile now...... This question has been asked a few times before (links below).

[Another Similar Question with PGSQL, Vagrant, Induction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725855/trouble-connecting-to-postgresql-database-in-vagrant-guest-box-with-induction-fr)

[Same question except with pgAdmin](http://www.bentedder.com/use-pgadmin-access-postgres-database-within-vagrant-box/)

[Connecting to Vagrant PGSQL from Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426839/how-to-access-to-postgresql-on-vagranted-virtual-machine)

I've read the Vagrant documentation for [Networking](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/) and for [enter link description here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html). Also, I've tried to resolve my problem with this useful link [http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-remote) but it still not working.

The error that I'm experiencing is this

```
Is the server running on host "192.168.50.4" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What I have is a Mac OSX with a rails application and I have a vagrant environment that is running PGSQL 9.2.6. The database on vagrant and on my Mac OSX are the same database with the exact users, privileges, and schema.

What I want to do is to get my rails app to connect to the 9.2.6 PGSQL on vagrant.

Here is a snippet of my database.yml file for my rails app:

```
DB_HOST = "192.168.50.4" #This ip is taken from vagrant example
DB_NAME = "testing"
DB_USERNAME = "postgres_user"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DB_PORT = "5432"
```

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

I have postgresql running as shown with `pas aux | grep postgres`

What seems to be causing the problem has to be either the `pg_hba.conf` file or the `postgresql.conf` file.

I've set my listen_address to '*'

```
listen_address = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

From the other stack overflow questions that seemed to be the problem but it still doesn't work for me.

Here is my pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                    trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# Connecting to postgresql on vagrant from ohloh and ohloh-ui
host    openhub_testing  all          192.168.50.4/32        trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Although I do specify a user and password in my database.yml I regardless put everything on trust because I was having problems connecting to pgsql from vagrant.

Can anyone point out what I haven't tried yet. I'm out of options to try. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed the pg_hba.conf file. Instead of 192.168.50.4/32, I needed to add 192.168.50.1/32.